# String data not inserting into MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hello in the following MySQL query I am attempting to insert a string where it says "notes" but I keep getting an error and the data does not submit. However, if I pass a number it successfully works.

```
`insert into lecture_notes(teacher_id, class_id, notes, sent_on)
values(?,?,?, now());`, 
      [
          data1, data2, "testing testing"
      ],
```

//Following is the error I keep getting
{
"success": 0,
"data": "Error. Unable to post notes.",
"error_type": {
"code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
"errno": 1054,
"sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'notes' in 'field list'",
"sqlState": "42S22",
"index": 0,
"sql": "insert into lecture_notes(teacher_id, class_id, notes, sent_on)\n            values(28,27,note, now());"
}
}

Comment: *I keep getting an error*: please edit your question to show the full error message.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `notes`?

Comment: Also add the response of `desc lecture_notes;` so that the data types can be seen properly.

Comment: @GMB Its varchar(80) utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: I edited my question and added the error I keep seeing

Comment: please add output of `show create table lecture_notes;` to your question

Comment: It worked now. There was a syntax error in my code before hitting this query. Thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unknown column 'notes' in 'field list'` This clearly means that your table does not have any column named `notes`. Correct the column name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I do have that column. So thats not the issue because when I pass a number instead of  a string to test it, it works. But not when I pass a string.

Comment: I got it to work now. There was a syntax error in my code before hitting this query. Thank you..

Comment: Was it about the column name or about the data type? If it worked, do upvote please

Comment: It was somewhat related to that. But not specifically the column name because the name was matching. It was how I was passing the data into that column. Gave you upvote. Thanks